# Computing a global threshold using Otsu's method for a ROI in an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have obtained a ROI using [`roipoly`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html) in an image. Is there a way that one can compute a global threshold using [Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) for that area only? If one uses the [`graythresh(I)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) function, all pixels including those outside the ROI are taken into account in the computation of the threshold. Is there a way that can only make use of the pixels in the ROI?

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you simply give the list of relevant pixels to `graythresh`. If you look at the code:

```
edit graythresh
```

You will see that the image `I` is immediately flattened (line 44 in R2013b):

```
I = im2uint8(I(:));
```

This means that `graythresh` can work with a vector of pixel values just as with an image, so doing

```
level = graythresh(I(mask));
```

should work just fine.